# Camel Kafka issues authentication with Kerberos in Native Mode

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, quarkus-native

Currently I'm working on some camel-quarkus (Red hat distribution 2.7.x version) based project that make use of the camel-kafka component as a consumer and producer actually. I'm actually testing it in an OCP cluster.

For configuring the component we have something like this for the Kafka consumer endpoint i'm using:

```
 @Named("myConsumerEndpoint")
    public KafkaEndpoint kafkaConsumerEndpoint() {

        KafkaEndpoint kafkaEndpoint = context.getEndpoint("kafka:" + subscriberTopic, KafkaEndpoint.class);

        KafkaConfiguration kafkaConfiguration = new KafkaConfiguration();
        kafkaConfiguration.setTopic(topic);
        kafkaConfiguration.setBrokers(brokers);
        kafkaConfiguration.setAutoOffsetReset("earliest");
        kafkaConfiguration.setClientId(clientid);
        kafkaConfiguration.setSecurityProtocol(SecurityProtocol.SASL_SSL.name());
        kafkaConfiguration.setSaslJaasConfig(
                "com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required useKeyTab=true      storeKey=true keyTab="...
         
        // Other kafkaConfigs for polling, etcetera!
...

        return kafkaEndpoint;
    }
```

We pass in that case the -Djava.security.krb5.conf and works without issues in JVM mode.

However, I'm getting issues with trying the Native mode on this, specially because I've started getting several errors when starting this related to KerberosLogin.
I see that is able to read the content of the krb5 file in the container, but then I'm getting a big exception coming like this (with Krb5 debug enabled):

```
>>> KrbAsReq creating message
getKDCFromDNS using UDP
getKDCFromDNS using TCP
        [Krb5LoginModule] authentication failed 
Cannot locate KDC
2023-06-14 18:30:43,736 ERROR [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (main) Error starting CamelContext (camel-1) due to exception thrown: Failed to start route kafkaPublisherRoute because of null: org.apache.camel.FailedToStartRouteException: Failed to start route kafkaPublisherRoute because of null
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doWarmUpRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:306)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:189)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartCamel(AbstractCamelContext.java:3365)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStartContext(AbstractCamelContext.java:3033)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doStart(AbstractCamelContext.java:2988)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.start(AbstractCamelContext.java:2649)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:262)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.doStart(CamelMain.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMain.startEngine(CamelMain.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.main.CamelMainRuntime.start(CamelMainRuntime.java:49)
    at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.CamelBootstrapRecorder.start(CamelBootstrapRecorder.java:45)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.CamelBootstrapProcessor$boot173480958.deploy(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:110)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:70)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:123)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:67)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultChannel.doStart(DefaultChannel.java:126)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.doStart(Pipeline.java:224)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.doStart(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.startChildServices(RouteService.java:396)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.doWarmUp(RouteService.java:193)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.RouteService.warmUp(RouteService.java:121)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:439)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:289)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:301)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.DefaultKafkaClientFactory.getProducer(DefaultKafkaClientFactory.java:29)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.createProducer(KafkaProducer.java:228)
    at org.apache.camel.component.kafka.KafkaProducer.doStart(KafkaProducer.java:160)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.internalAddService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1577)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.addService(AbstractCamelContext.java:1498)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.doStart(SendProcessor.java:244)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.start(BaseService.java:119)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:113)
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:130)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.errorhandler.RedeliveryErrorHandler.doStart(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:1670)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ChildServiceSupport.start(ChildServiceSupport.java:60)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot locate KDC
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:184)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:192)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:81)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:105)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:484)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:428)
```

At the moment I've followed some tips and some suggestion to make some progress
considering the following:

- Register for reflection all required classes of my code and other potential classes as well.
- Define the java.security.krb5.conf and sun.security.krb5.debug properties in the additional build arguments property.
- Added the the initialize-at-run-time=org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin argument as well, based on some comments in this topic:
  [Error when trying to access Kafka with Quarkus in native mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130420/error-when-trying-to-access-kafka-with-quarkus-in-native-mode)

However, the situation is still the same and I'm not sure if there's any other option I can try at least to have a better view of the real problem or if i'm missing some configuration to make it work on the native side of things.

Appreciate any help/feedback on this!

Comment: From what I understand, there is currently no native support for Kafka + Kerberos in Quarkus or Camel Quarkus. Even if you get past the 'Cannot locate KDC' issue, you are likely to hit further problems.